# How to remove ALL foreign keys in mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, information-schema

Is there some sort of system table I can delete records from that contain the foreign key constraints defined in a database?

I have taken all the FKs from different clones of the databases and I just want to sync them up and also to make their names consistent.

I know of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, but I think that's read-only as noted in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-introduction.html#information-schema-usage-notes)

> Although you can select INFORMATION_SCHEMA as the default database with a USE statement, you can only read the contents of tables, not perform INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operations on them.

And I know I can do a query that would just use information schema to spit out a script, but I'd rather avoid that step as I won't be able to execute that in a Liquibase script that gets applied different instances.

Answer (score 0):

Execute this...

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't add or remove foreign key constraints without using ALTER TABLE.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, there’s no DROP CONSTRAINT, you have to use DROP FOREIGN KEY instead:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name`
    DROP FOREIGN KEY `id_name_fk`;
```

You might have to drop the index too because simply removing foreign key doesn’t remove the index.

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` 
    DROP INDEX  `id_name_fk`;
```

An alternative to temporarily disable all the foreign keys:
`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`

When you need to turn it on:
`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;`